# How to align lottie animation to the bottom of @Composable LottieAnimation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lottie, android-lottie

I am using compose lottie to load animation, I want animation to be bottom aligned,
I am applying background to `LottieAnimation` when animation is playing I can see background at the bottom I want to know if there is any way to bottom align loaded animation in `LottieAnimation`.

My code:

```
@Composable
fun AnimatedDecoration(
  @RawRes val lottieAnimationId: Int,
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  @ColorRes val backgroundColor: Int? = null
) {
  val composition by
    rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(lottieAnimationId))

  val localModifier =
    backgroundColor?.let {
      modifier.background(color = colorResource(id = it), shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
    }
      ?: modifier

  LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
    iterations = iterations,
    modifier = localModifier
  )
}
```

attaching screenshot for reference.

[image]

As you can see animation is playing at the centre but I want to align it to bottom or wrap hight of `LottieAnimation` to hight of animation.